# Why wasn't there a TSM vs RNG tiebreaker game?

Tags: league-of-legends, competitive-gaming

In Worlds 2016, both the teams are 3-3 in the group stage. Why was RNG promoted over TSM without a tiebreaker match when their scores are the same?

Comment: Here is the [Meta Discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12044/28182) on this question for those interested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In group D, TSM and RNG both went 3-3. However, in the direct matchup, RNG had already gone 2-0 vs TSM. Due to that there was no tiebreaker game since RNG had already won the matchup.